# AJAX Contact Form sending empty parameters

Tags: php, ajax

An ajax function returns a form. I want to send this form values to the other ajax function.

Chrome doesn't have a problem, but Firefox can't do this and sends empty values!

For example, I return a edit form with ajax and the edit button function can't get/post form values.

Comment: How about you post on here the relevant form as it is presented in the HTML output (ie html source code) - as this seems to be a browser issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have event handler issues.  Maybe all your event handling code is run prior to your new form existing in the dom?  Without sample code, we have no idea how you are trying to accomplish this.  Maybe, in your form tag, include an onsubmit attribute to handle your submission:

```
<form onsubmit="sendForm(this); return false;">
<script>
    function sendForm(obj) {
        var data = $(obj).serialize();
        $.post('myEndpoint.cfm',data, function(response){
            // response handling code here.

        });
    }
</script>
```